# Что почитать по Perl?

Tags: perl

Уже прочитал: "Изучаем перл", "Перл - изучаем глубже", "Programming Perl". Что можете ещё посоветовать почитать на русском (возможно статьи или ещё что-то в этом роде).

---

Или помогите придумать задачу для повышения уровня знаний(умений).

Answer (score 3):

[Modern Perl](http://onyxneon.com/books/modern_perl/) и [Higher-Order Perl](http://hop.perl.plover.com/). Причем обе в обязательном порядке. Хоть и не на русском -- еще не переведены.

Comment: С английским проблемы . Но всё же спасибо

Answer (score 2):

Ну если вы действительно осилили эти три книги, то сможете написать любую программу на этом языке. Смысл читать что-либо ещё по Perl есть только для решения какой-нибудь конкретной задачи с использованием этого языка, если даже после прочтения приведённых вами книг вы не представляете себе с чего начать решение этой конкретной задачи.

Comment: Проблема в том - что вроде освоил сам язык , а где использовать не знаю (точнее, что можно написать) .

Comment: Ну, если вы не написали ни одной практически-значимой программы, то значит вы язык не освоили, а освоили его синтаксис... А вообще язык надо изучать наоборот - от задач. Я так изучил Питон - надо было автоматизировать работу с тысячами коммутаторов. Что бы сделать представление всей аналитической информации я изучил поглубже JavaScript+html5.

Answer (score 1):

Что написано первой строчкой в предисловии к "Programming Perl"? "Perl - это язык, который поможет вам выполнить вашу работу" (как-то так). Это не C++, о котором написано более 9000 книг "учим за 24 часа", "паттерны на", "решение хитроумных задач на" и тд. Освоили - отлично. Теперь можно делать работу. Притом в 90% случаев эта "работа" будет заключаться в том, чтобы связать между собой несколько модулей из CPAN.

Может, вам следовало задать другой вопрос? Например - "как придумать себе задачу с целью прокачать скил программирования, если самому вроде никакой проги не нужно?".

Comment: Спасибо за совет , сейчас немного изменю вопрос .

Answer (score 1):

Наверняка Вы уже писали какие-то более-менее полезные программы. Попробуйте переписать их на перле.

Comment: Эти программы были в основном на C# и PHP .

Comment: Perl очень широко применяется для веб-программирования. Можно сказать, это основное его коммерческое применение. Если Вы писали проекты на  PHP, попробуйте их написать на перле. Модуль CGI в помощь.

Comment: Спасибо , попробую простой чат для начала написать.

Comment: Не знаю как насчет создания GUI на перле под Windows, для никсов есть модуль для программирования в GTK+. Сам как-то им баловался. 
Впрочем, есть модуль для Qt. Наверняка имеется его реализация для виндов.

Answer (score 0):

На мой взгляд, после "Изучаем Perl" нужна просто настольная книга с рецептами типовых решений - такая как "Perl:сборник рецептов" Тома Кристиансена. Вторая полезная книжечка - "Perl отладчик" Ричарда Фоули. Обе выходили на русском языке в издательстве Питер.

Не нужно использовать всякие хитроумные конструкции в повседневной жизни, если вам нужно создавать нормальный работающий код - стандартных конструкций, кака правило, вполне достаточно.  Знание различных "хитроумных" штучек прийдет с опытом, если в них возникнет реальная необходимость. Основной же принцип Perl - одну и ту же задачу можно решить разными способами.

Answer (score -2):

А такое слабо: [Perl для профессиональных программистов. Регулярные выражения](http://my-shop.ru/shop/books/538312.html)?  Шучу! Может будет полезна и такая книга со временем.